# how to select date programatically to date picker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-layout

I have simple created a demo for understanding package 'package:date_picker_timeline/date_picker_timeline.dart'

here I have place DatePicker and 3 text button with caption yesterday today and tomorrow

like, I select yesterday ,date picker should be shown yesterday's date as selected

so what could should I implement to onPressed of text button

here is my code

```
class _HomeScreen2State extends State<HomeScreen2> {
  DateTime selecteddate=DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

              ),
              child: DatePicker(
                DateTime.now(),
                initialSelectedDate: selecteddate,
                selectionColor: Colors.black,
                selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
                onDateChange: (date) {

                },
              ),
            ),
            Text('You have selected\n'+DateFormat.yMMMd().format(selecteddate).toString()),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                //what code to write here to achieve it
              }, child: Text('Yesterday')),
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                //what code to write here to achieve it
              }, child: Text('Today')),
              TextButton(onPressed: (){
                //what code to write here to achieve it
              }, child: Text('Tomorrow'))
            ],)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: cant find any option to select, only scroll can be applied using this package

Comment: For yesterday, I used   selecteddate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));
              and so on with tomorrow .add but date picker not showing selected that date...

Comment: I can't find any functionality to select the date

Answer (score 0):

To make the **datepicker** select the date based on **yesterday**, **today** and **tomorrow**,
you can easily update the **initialSelectedDate** onPressed of each button to their date accordingly

```dart
TextButton(
 onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      selecteddate = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
controller.animateToDate(selecteddate);
   });
 }, 
 child: const Text('Yesterday'),
),
```

Adding controller animate the date to the selected date but does not set the active color

Comment: can u pls provide code.....

Comment: okay i will edit the answer now

Comment: when i check out the project the maintainer has updated it since last year and this is also part of the issue so best way to get around it is to fork the repo and edit it